# Can we use PWM on the cheap RX{n}[letter]-TX{n}[letter] Integrated Circuits

Tags: integrated-circuit, pwm, remote-control

The market has been inundated with cheap RC toys. Most of them use the RX/TX Integrated Circuits that have 5 to 9 functions:

- [PT0090 Series Datasheet](http://www.pti-ic.com/new/manage/doc_datasheet/PT0090%20%20%20%20%20PT8A9701-974-974L-2.pdf)
- [RX2/TX2 Datasheet](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/indexer.php?file=DSA00179657.pdf&dir=Datasheet-098&keywords=remote+controlled+car+tx+rx+turbo&database=user-highscore#)

All of them operate on an ON/OFF state.

Has anyone tried to feed a PWM signal to these and see if they have enough frequency output on the Receiving end?

Comment: Are you trying to implement a poor-man's proportional steering / throttle control?

Comment: @Dave Yeap, you got it quite right.

Comment: @Gustavo, these parts sound quite interesting. I was just looking around but can't find them at my usual shops. Where do you buy them?

Comment: @wollud1969 I've never got to the point of investigating a supplier. I've "sourced" mine from discarded cheap RC toys that I had laying around.

Comment: Technically, the answer is yes.  The more important question is what the PWM frequency limit would be, with anything from perhaps half a Hertz to a few hundred being believable without consulting the data sheet.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : After going through some other stuff about PPM and PWM and the details of it under Arduino Interfacing with Hobby RC, I've got to the point where I'm sure it can be done. What I now need to assess is the LOW and HIGH limits of the PWM frequency I can 'squeeze' in. I'm assuming it transmits the data inside a 'frame', something like the 20 nano or mili seconds on the RC. Will have to do some probing and some calcs to get to some hard info, then I'll probably answer my own question.

Answer (score 1):

The second of those datasheets talks about using a 1khz PWM signal internally for communicating, so I suspect transmitting PWM through them will not work.